# RUBY Grouping data by parsed REST JSON result property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, group-by

First of all, I am very new to Ruby so go easy on me! I have the parsed JSON in my sourceHash variable and I am trying to group data by the "displayName" property. The JSON format is something like this (I've simplified it without changing the structure):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            "title": "my blog post",
            "history": {
                "createdOn": "2017-09-18 15:38:26",
                "createdBy": {
                    "userName": "myUserName",
                    "displayName": "Michael W."
                }
            }
        },
        { ... same stuff for some other blog post ... },
        { ... same stuff for some other blog post ... },
        { ... same stuff for some other blog post ... }
    ]
}
```

Basically, there are two things I want to do.
Imagine this list as "list of blog posts including the author data" of them.

- Find the person who posted the most amount of entries
- Get the top 10 bloggers, ordered by their blog post count, descending

So the first would look something like this:

> > Michael W. (51 posts)

However, the second one would look like this:

> > - Michael Wayne (51 posts)
> > - Emilia Clarke (36 posts)
> > - Charlize Theron (19 posts)
> > - Scarlett Johansson (7 posts)

I've played around these queries, trying to merge my LINQ logic into this, but I failed... (I'm a Ruby noob so be easy!)

```
sourceHash = @mainData["results"]

hashSetPrimary = sourceHash.group_by{|h| h['history']['createdBy']['displayName']}

return hashSetPrimary
```

So long story short, I am trying to write to separate queries that would group the data by those criteria, any help is appreciated as I can't find any proper way to do it.

Comment: Try something like `hashSetPrimary = hashSetPrimary.map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }.sort_by(:last)`.

Comment: @henrebotha it is complaining it can't find the count method `undefined method 'count' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to look at your hash syntax. When you define a hash using `h = { "foo": "bar" }`, the key is **not** actually a string, but rather a symbol. Therefore accessing `h["foo"]` is not going to work (it will return `nil`); you have to access it as `h[:foo]`.

So addressing that, this does what you need:

```
sourceHash = @mainData[:results]

hashSetPrimary = sourceHash.group_by{ |h| h.dig(:history, :createdBy, :displayName) }
                           .map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }
                           .sort_by(&:last)

return hashSetPrimary
```

`Hash#dig` requires Ruby 2.3+. If you are running on a lower version, you can do something like this instead of `dig`:

```
h[:history] && h[:history][:createdBy] && h[:history][:createdBy][:displayName]
```

Comment: I must be missing something here because it is complaining `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. I am not sure what it is referring to by [], probably one of the nodes I am trying to access? e.g. [:history] etc. Sorry I am being so daft, I started learning ruby yesterday lol...

Comment: That's what I get: `statsTry.rb:127:in 'block in myMethodTest': undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from statsTry.rb:127:in 'each'
        from statsTry.rb:127:in 'group_by'
        from statsTry.rb:127:in 'myMethodTest'
        from statsTry.rb:175:in '<main>'`

Comment: Okay but I don't have your file in front of me, I don't know which is line 127.

Comment: 127 is literally `hashSetPrimary = sourceHash.group_by{ |h| h[:history][:createdBy][:displayName] }`

Comment: Does any of your parsed JSON lack a `:history`, `:createdBy`, or `:displayName`?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure, the JSON I get from the service is kind of huge. They *might* be missing under some json objects.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156989/discussion-between-michael-wayne-and-henrebotha).